# Переместить unique_ptr из vector в deque

Tags: c++, c++11

Необходимо перенести объект типа `std::unique_ptr` из вектора в дек.

[Пример кода](https://ideone.com/CYuJqW):

```
using UPtr = std::unique_ptr<int>;

std::deque<UPtr> d;
std::vector<UPtr> v;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    v.emplace_back(new int(i));
}

for (const auto& item : v) {
    d.emplace_front(std::move(item));
}
```

Но неожиданно возникает ошибка компиляции:

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]'
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:81:0,
                 from prog.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:356:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
```

Насколько я понимаю, должен использоваться перемещающий конструктор, а не копирующий, но этого не происходит.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в квалификаторе `const`.
В цикле

```
for (const auto& item : v) {
    d.emplace_front(std::move(item));
}
```

переменная `item` имеет тип `const std::unique_ptr<int>&`, соответственно при вызове `std::move` получаем тип `const std::unique_ptr<int>&&`. Перемещающего конструктора, который бы принимал этот тип, нет, поэтому компилятор использует копирующий конструктор, что и приводит к ошибке.

---

Похожая ошибка рассмотрена у Скотта Мейерса в книге "Эффективный и современный C++" в разделе 5.1.

Comment: Эм.. А какое в итоге решение?

Comment: Убрать квалификатор 'const' ;-)

Comment: @Qwertiy очевидно нужно убрать `const`.

Comment: @alexolut, да, что-то я перемудрил. Почему-то подумал, что const нужен. А нужна-то ссылка, а не он.

Comment: Я бы сказал, что проблема шире, чем в просто отсутствии конструктора. Как только что-то перемещается - как угодно! - это что-то изменяется, а значит, такой объект не может быть const в принципе.

Comment: @Harry, возможность перемещать `const` объекты есть, просто нужно определить соответствующий конструктор. Другой вопрос: нужен ли такой конструктор.

Comment: @PavelParshin определение такого конструктора потребует добавления `mutable` ко всем членам класса, которые действительно требуют перемещения (не копирования). Что в итоге приведет к тому, что пропадет смысл в `const` функциях. В общем, хорошего мало.